# Bijection between prime ideals of $\Bbb C[x,y]$ which contains the ideal $(xy-1)$ and the prime ideals in $\Bbb C[x]$ which does not contain $x$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

> Show that there exists a bijection between prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ which contains the ideal $(xy-1)$ and the prime ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ which does not contain $x$.

I know: 
$$  \mathbb{C}[x,y]\Big/(xy-1)\cong \mathbb{C}\left[x,\frac{1}{x}\right]  $$ and also, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156639/can-the-prime-ideals-of-a-a-be-identified-with-those-prime-ideals-of-a-which).

Comment: Is this question a special case of this question here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280885/bijection-between-prime-ideals-of-r-p-and-prime-ideals-of-r-contained-in-p?rq=1

Comment: I don't know $ \operatorname{Spec}R_{\mathfrak p}$

Comment: The spectrum is the topological space of prime ideals. I don't think the topology is relevant here though.

Comment: Hmm, continuing your "chain of isomorphisms" we have $\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy-1)\cong \Bbb C\left[x,\frac{1}{x}\right]\cong \Bbb C[x]_x$, where we've localized at the multiplicative closed subset $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots \}$. Now, by a well-known result the prime ideals of $C[x,y]/(xy-1)$ are exactly the prime ideals of $\Bbb C[x,y]$ which contains the ideal $(xy-1)$. From there it follows the bijection, I think. Maybe I'll post a full answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post my answer for completeness.

First, for a commutative ring $R$, let $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ be the set of prime ideals of $R$. By Krull's theorem (about the existence of maximal ideals), the above set isn't empty.

In order to get our desire bijection I will use three results, letting the proofs as exercises for the OP. The first two are given below, whereas the third one is the bijection given in my answer linked in the question above.

**Theorem 1:** If $\phi\colon R\rightarrow R'$ is an isomorphism of commutative rings, then there is a bijection $\overline{\phi}\colon \operatorname{Spec}(R)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(R')$.

Informally, by the isomorphism we can think as $R$ and $R'$ being the same ring, so they will have the same prime ideals.

**Theorem 2:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. If we denote by $\operatorname{Var}(I)=\{P\in \operatorname{Spec}(R): I\subseteq P\}$, then there is a bijection $\psi\colon \operatorname{Var}(I)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(R/I)$.

This follows from the [correspondence theorem for rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813978/133781) and the [third isomorphism theorem for rings](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThirdRingIsomorphismTheorem.html).

---

Finally, we're ready to find our bijection. We can work more generally in an arbitrary field $K$. As I indicated (following the OP), we have the following isomorphisms $$ K[x,y]\big/\langle xy-1\rangle\cong K[x,x^{-1}]\cong K[x]_x.$$

Now, set $A=\bigl\{\mathfrak{P}\in \operatorname{Spec}\bigl(K[x]\bigr): x\notin \mathfrak{P}\bigr\}$, i.e., the set of prime ideals of $K[x]$ which don't contain $x$, and $B=\operatorname{Var}\bigl(\langle xy-1\rangle\bigr)$, i.e., the set of prime ideals of $K[x,y]$ which contain the ideal $\langle xy-1\rangle$.

By the theorem given in my answer linked in the question we have the bijection: $$\alpha\colon A\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(K[x]_x).$$

On the other hand, by theorem 1 we have the bijection: $$\beta\colon \operatorname{Spec}\bigl(K[x]_x\bigr)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}\Bigl(K[x,y]\big/\langle xy-1\rangle\Bigr).$$

Analogously, by theorem 2 we have the bijection: $$\theta\colon \operatorname{Spec}\Bigl(K[x,y]\big/\langle xy-1\rangle\Bigr)\longrightarrow B.$$

Finally, our desired bijection is $\theta\circ \beta\circ \alpha\colon A\longrightarrow B$ and we're done.

Comment: Could you please undelete your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2441687/242) here, since I added an answer which (hopefully)  makes it comprehensible to the OP.

Comment: Mr. @Bill Dubuque after seeing your answer I guess I can undelete mine, but I'm using the app for Android users so right now I can't undelete it. I will ASAP.