# Two fractions in $R[\frac{1}{x}]$ are equal iff $(\exists n\ge 0)(x^n\cdot ax^i=x^n\cdot bx^j)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Given a ring $R$ and an element $x\in R$, we can adjoint the inverse of $x$ by ring extension $R[\frac{1}{x}]=R[x,y]/\langle xy-1\rangle$, so any elements in $R[\frac{1}{x}]$ is of form $\frac{a}{x^i}$.

I aim to prove that in the ring $R[\frac{1}{x}]$, for any two elements $\frac{a}{x^i},\frac{b}{x^j}$, they are equal iff $(\exists n\ge 0)(x^n\cdot ax^j=x^n\cdot bx^i)$.

It sounds quite counter-intuitive since I expect $ax^j= bx^i$ is enough. Why it doesn't hold, may I please ask some counterexamples?

I tried to prove it but have not found a way yet. Could someone please tell me how to prove the fact: Two fractions in $R[\frac{1}{x}]$ are equal iff $(\exists n\ge 0)(x^n\cdot ax^j=x^n\cdot bx^i)$?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I have not seen the definition of localization in my algebra course, I googled the construction and wonder why we make the equivalence relation $t(r_1s_2 − r_2s_1) = 0$. And also it does not directly give the desired conclusion because here we require a multiple of $x$, instead of an arbitary element in $R$, playing the role of $t$. If possible, may I please ask for an argument does not involve the usage of definition of localization? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you a have typo in your post: $a/x^i = b/x^j$ iff $\exists n \geq 0$ s.t. $x^n \cdot ax^j = x^n \cdot bx^i$.

Comment: @Federico Yes...Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @PropositionX there is another answer that you will find useful.

Comment: I added some remarks to my answer that may help you to better understand these matters - which are often puzzling to most who first encounter these topics. Please feel welcome to ask questions if anything is not clear,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that could go wrong is if you try to invert a nilpotent element. For example, let $R = k[\epsilon] / (\epsilon^2)$ for some field $k$, and attempt to invert the element $\epsilon \in R$. Then the extended ring is $S = k[\epsilon, t] / (\epsilon^2, t \epsilon - 1)$. At this point, we want to say that $1 / \epsilon^0 \neq 1 / \epsilon^1$, since $\epsilon \neq 1$ in $R$.

However, we can take the relation $t \epsilon = 1$ in $S$, and multiply it by $\epsilon$ to find that $t \epsilon^2 = 0 = \epsilon$. At this point the relation $t \epsilon = 1$ turns into $0 = 1$, and so $S$ is in fact the zero ring. So *every* expression involving fractions in $\epsilon$ are equal! This demonstrates the need for that extra $x^n$ in the criterion you have there: in this case, it's saying that the expressions are equal for some power of $\epsilon$. In particular, higher powers of $\epsilon$ are all $0$ and so everything is equal in the extended ring.

The moral of the story is basically that "bad stuff" happens when we invert nilpotent elements or zero-divisors: the theory developed around localisation gives good tools for dealing with how to do this. The "universal property of localisation" is also a very powerful way to look at how to introduce fractions into commutative rings.

Answer (score 2):

In [many prior answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=localization+equivalence+relation) you can find explanations motivating the definition of the equivalence relation in the common pair-based normal form construction of localizations. But this does not provide immediate intuition for the alternative presentation-based construction of the fraction ring [(localization)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring)  $\rm\,S^{-1} R\,$ as, *conceptually*, the *universal* way of adjoining inverses of $\rm\,S\,$ to $\rm\,R\,$ via  $\rm\,S^{-1} R = R[x_i]/(s_i x_i - 1),\,$ as in your special case. This presentation-based approach allows us  to exploit to the hilt the *universal properties* of quotient rings and polynomial rings to *quickly* and *easily* construct and derive basic properties of localizations (avoiding the many tedious verifications always "left for the reader" in the more commonly pair=based normal-forms approach).

In this presentation-based approach there is no need to unintuitively massage an equivalence relation to account for annihilated elements. Rather we can directly compute what is annihilated by a simple (widely-overlooked) trick: $ $ if $\rm\,r\in R\,$ lies in the  kernel of $\rm\, R\to S^{-1} R = R[x]/(1\!-\!sx),\,$ then $\rm\,r \in (1\!-\!sx)R[x]\,\Rightarrow\, r = (1\!-\!sx)f(x)\,$ so by comparing coefficients we obtain

$\quad \begin{eqnarray}\rm n = deg\, f\quad and\quad  r &=&\rm (1\!-\!sx)\,f(x) &\Rightarrow&\ \rm f(0) = r\qquad\,\ \ \ via\ \ coef\ x^0 \\
\rm\Rightarrow\  (1\!+\!sx\!+\dots+\!(sx)^n)\, r &=&\rm (1\!-\!(sx)^{n+1})\, f(x) &\Rightarrow&\ \rm f(0)\,s^{n+1}\! = 0\quad via\ \ coef\ x^{n+1} \\
& & &\Rightarrow&\ \rm\ \ \,\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{r\ s^{n+1} = 0}
\end{eqnarray}$

As Xam wrote in his answer, this immediately yields the result that you seek. 
 and using the above proof requires no prior knowledge of the (pair-based) localization construction.

If you introspect on the construction used in the pair-based approach you will find that it boils down to choosing $\rm\color{#0a0}{constant}$ normal-form reps of equivalence classes in the above quotient rings 
$$\rm f(x) = s^n f(x)/s^n = s^n(f_n x^n+\cdots +f_1 x+ f_0)/s^n = (f_n+ f_1 s^{n-1} + f_0 s^n)/s^n = \color{#0a0}{r/s^n},\ r\in R$$

analogous to how [Hamilton's pair-based construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658/23500) of $\,\Bbb C = \Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$ chooses $\rm\color{#0a0}{least\ degree}$ (= linear) normal form reps $\rm\,a+bx\,$ of polynomials $\rm \bmod\, x^2+1\,$ with the ring operations *and congruence* [transported to the pair normal form reps](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1145277/242), e.g. transported multiplication of pairs is

$\rm\begin{eqnarray}\rm (a,\ b) &&\rm (c,\ d) &\!\!=&\rm (ac\!\color{#000}{\bf -}\!bd,\quad\ \  ad\!+\!bc)\\[.2em]
\rm i.e.\  \bmod{\color{#c00}{\,x^2\!+1}}\!:\ \ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv -1}\ \,\Rightarrow\,\  (a\! +\! b\color{#c00}x)&&\rm(c\! +\! d\color{#c00}{ x})\, &\!\!\!\rm\,\equiv&\rm (ac\!\color{#c00}{\bf -}\!bd) + (ad\!+\!bc)\, x\\[.3em]
\rm i.e.\quad\, (a\! +\! b{\it i}\,)&&\rm(c\! +\! d {\it i}\,)\, &\!\! =\,&\rm (ac\!\color{#000}{\bf -}\!bd) + (ad\!+\!bc)\,{\it i}\end{eqnarray}$

The pair-based localization construction is precisely analogous, i.e. the construction transports the ring operations *and congruence* to normal form reps of the equivalence classes of the quotient rings. When viewed in this way, the equivalence relation imposed on the fraction pair reps $\rm\,(r,s^n)\,$ arises *naturally* and no longer seems contrived.

This is a protoypical example of ubiquitous techniques employed in normal form computation in quotient objects, so it is well-worth the effort to study it carefully.

For further discussion (including literature references) see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162037/242)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is much easier then my brute-force method. Learnt a lot from this answer!

Answer (score 1):

We have the following isomorphisms $$R[x,x^{-1}]\cong R[x,y]/(xy-1)\cong R[x]_x.$$
The last ring is the localization of $R[x]$ at the multiplicatively closed subset $S=\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$. Now, by definition of localization we have $\frac{a}{x^i}=\frac{b}{x^j}$ if only if there is an element $x^n\in S $ such that $x^n(ax^j-bx^i)=0$, i.e., $x^n\cdot ax^j=x^n\cdot bx^i$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have not seen the definition of localization, and I doubt why the definition os like this. May I please ask for some further explaination without the usage of definition of localization?

Comment: @PropositionX I suggested to Xam to undelete this answer since I think that - with the help of the alternative approach in my answer - it may prove to be more comprehensible to you (and possibly to other readers too).