# Example for a ring $R[\frac{1}{a}],a\in R$ such that $\frac{u}{a^m} = \frac{v}{a^n}$ but $ua^n \ne va^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

For a ring $R$, adjoint a inverse of an element $a\in R$ by taking $R[\frac{1}{a}]\cong R[x]/<ax-1>$.

> I am stucking on constructing an explicit example such that $\frac{u}{a^m} = \frac{v}{a^n}$ but  $ua^n \ne va^m$. I know that to do this I require $a$ is not a nilpotent (I have deduced that if it is nilpotent then we would always have a zero ring) and $R$ not an integral domain.

So could someone tell me how to construct it, please?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: @Mr.Chip Because I have just find the sufficient condition of two fractions are equal in such a ring, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441481/two-fractions-in-r-frac1x-are-equal-iff-exists-n-ge-0xn-cdot-axi

Comment: You want $ua^n \neq va^m$ to hold in $R$ or in $R[\frac{1}{a}]$?

Comment: @MooS I need it in $R$.

Comment: Then it is very easy. In fact, let $a$ be a nilpotent. Then $\frac{1}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$, but $1 \cdot 1 \neq 0 \cdot 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be any ring - not an integral domain - and $a$ a zero-divisor, say $ab=0$. Consider $R[\frac{1}{a}]$.

Then $\frac{b}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$ in $R[\frac{1}{a}]$, but $b \cdot 1 \neq 0 \cdot 1$ in $R$.